# How do I give my `<div>` elements a animation entry when my website loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want my `<div>` contents to make a smooth entry when my website loads. They have to start appearing one after the other when the website loads. And also, the background image loads late as it is filtered by the `weatherType`.
This is a localWeather webpage which gives you the weather information based on where you open the page.

**Note:-** *Please post the code on other third party Web Development sites like `codepen.io` to access the API.*

Here is my Code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".text-center").fadeIn();
            var lon, lat, weatherType, ftemp, ktemp, ctemp, wspeed;

            if (navigator.geolocation) {

                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                        lon = position.coords.longitude;
                        lat = position.coords.latitude;
                        var api = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=' + lat + '&lon=' + lon + '&appid=bb4b778076b0c8c79c7eb8fcd1fd4330';
                        $.getJSON(api, function(data) {
                            // $("#data").html(api);
                            var city = data.city.name;
                            weatherType = data.list[0].weather[0].description;
       //weatherType="clear sky";
                            ktemp = data.list[0].main.temp;
                            console.log(ktemp);
                            ftemp = (9 / 5 * (ktemp - 273) + 32).toFixed(1);
                            ctemp = (5 / 9 * (ftemp - 32)).toFixed(1);
                            wspeed = data.list[0].wind.speed;
                            wspeed = (wspeed * 5 / 18).toFixed(1);
                            /* $("#city").addClass("animated fadein",function(){
        $("#city").html(city);
        }); */
        $("#city").addClass("animated fadein");
        $("#city").html(city);
                            $("#weatherType").html(weatherType);
                            $("#temp").html(ctemp + " &#8451;");
                            //$("[name='my-checkbox']").bootstrapSwitch();
                            $("#degree-toggle").attr("value", $("<div/>").html("&#8457;").text());
                            var celsius = true;
                            $("#degree-toggle").on("click", function() {
                                if (celsius === true) {
                                    $("#temp").html(ftemp + " &#8457;");
         $("#temp").fadeIn();
                                    $("#degree-toggle").attr("value", $("<div/>").html("&#8451;").text());
                                    celsius = false;
                                } else {
                                    $("#temp").html(ctemp + " &#8451;");
         $("#temp").fadeIn();
                                    $("#degree-toggle").attr("value", $("<div/>").html("&#8457;").text());
                                    celsius = true;
                                }
                            });
                            $("#wspeed").html(wspeed + " kmph");
       weatherType=weatherType.toLowerCase();
                            if (weatherType === "clear sky")
                                $("body").css("background-image", "url('https://static.pexels.com/photos/281260/pexels-photo-281260.jpeg')");
                            else if (weatherType === "few clouds")
                                $("body").css("background-image", "url('https://clearalliance.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/CLEAR-see-clear-flowers-e1422658973500.jpg')");
                            else if (weatherType === "cloudy")
                                $("body").css("background-image", "url('http://www.gazetteseries.co.uk/resources/images/5360796/')");
       else if (weatherType === "sunny")
           $("body").css("background-image","url('https://i2-prod.examiner.co.uk/incoming/article10372520.ece/ALTERNATES/s1227b/JS75768352.jpg')");
       else if (weatherType==="showers")
           $("body").css("background-image","url('http://ak8.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/1479838/thumb/1.jpg')");
                          else if(weatherType==="overcast clouds") 
                                $("body").css("background-image","url('https://patchegal.files.wordpress.com/2012/07/img_2406.jpg')");
                          else if(weatherType==="light rain")
                               $("body").css("background-image","url('https://i.ytimg.com/vi/LbAigABOm_E/maxresdefault.jpg')");
                         else
           $("body").css("background-image","url('https://www.almanac.com/sites/default/files/image_nodes/thanksgiving-weather.jpg')");
                        });
                    });
                }
            });
```

```css
.text-center{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700&amp;lang=en" /><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
     <div class="text-center" id="content">
      <div> <h1><b>Weather Today</b></h1></div><br/>
       <h2>Location : <span id="city"></span></h2> <br/>
       <h2>Weather : <span id="weatherType"></span></h2><br/>
       <h2>Temperature : <span id="temp">
     </span>
  <input type="button" id="degree-toggle"  checked="checked">
      </h2><br/>
     <h2>Wind Speed : <span id="wspeed"></span></h2><br/>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First I would use animations to achieve smooth entry, not only switch elements to visible.

Second I wouldn't write elements manually, what if you have 20 of them? What about 1000?

Start with a frame like this then adjust to your case:

**HTML**

```
<div id="elementsInThis">
  <div class="K">ELEMENT 1</div>
  <div class="K">ELEMENT 2</div>
  <div class="K">ELEMENT 3</div>
  <div class="K">ELEMENT 4</div>
  <div class="K">ELEMENT 5</div>
  <div class="K">ELEMENT 6</div>
  <div class="K">ELEMENT 7</div>
  <div class="K">ELEMENT 8</div>
  <div class="K">ELEMENT 9</div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var delay = 0;

function animate(element, delay){
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        element.style.display = 'block';
    }, delay*1000)
}

var elements = document.getElementById("elementsInThis").childNodes;
var onlydivs = Object.keys(elements).forEach(function(index, element){
    if (elements[element].nodeType !== Node.TEXT_NODE) 
    animate(elements[element], delay++);
});
```

**CSS**

```
.K{
  display: none;
  background: red;
  border: solid 2px black;
  animation-name: appear;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes appear{from{left:-300px;opacity:0} to{left:0;opacity:1}}
```

Here you can see it in action:

[js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vzmfhfd2/)

Modify animation and delay to your liking, also bind to your own parent and make a better selecor of children if you have more complex ones. This is just a demo but principle is the same you do the following:

- You wanna leverage CSS to make proper (or find someone else's) animation and set default display of element to none (might wanna use visibility instead if your HTML breaks apart)
- make a delay function with fixed delay step (i used step 1 * 1000 ms)
- leverage `childNodes` `forEach()` and `Object.keys()` to avoid manually binding your CSS class with animation to elements
- you can have rest of the style in different CSS class if you like

Comment: Hi @DanteTheSmith. Appreciate your time spent on this. I have a question.
In the `JS` why have you used `if (elements[element].nodeType !== Node.TEXT_NODE) ` shouldn't it be `nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE`. As we are checking if the node has text `eg: city:` Please correct me if I am wrong. I am a bit confused here.

Comment: text in HTML has its own nodes, called text nodes. We don't wanna those, we wanna in this case div nodes. You might have to modify this to filter nodes based on class or something. Depends on your HTML  and DOM it generates.

Answer (score 2):

While I cannot give you an exact answer as I'm about to go home. What you can do is dedicate a separate function for your animation feature. Then in your script, you will each assign a setTimeout event for each element, giving each of them a specific delay before showing. Then you can add a transition or animation property on your element.

CSS

```
.elements {
//css here
}
```

JS

```
//delay = time in ms before show, element = element to show.
function letAnimate(delay, element){
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        element.style.display = 'block';
    }, delay);
}

function startAnimate(){
     letAnimate(1000, el1); //your first element which will show 1s after function call
     letAnimate(2000, el2); //2nd element, will show after 2s
     letAnimate(3000, el3); //3rd, 3s, so forth so on
}


window.onload = function(){ startAnimate(); };
//make this jquery on() or addEventListener.
//You don't want this function to override window.onload event.
```

Comment: Hi @Merigold. Could you please break down the code a little bit? 
in the function `startAnimate`, should the id values of the elements be used in the place of `el1`,`el2` and `el3` and I didn;t understand the comment `//make this jquery on() or addEventListener`. Why would that override my window loading funtion? Does that have any thing to do with `$(document).ready(function()`, like will it override it? And even if it works, which I am sure will, Where do I place it? If i place it after the existing code, wont the response be already shown first and then execute these set of codes?

Comment: @GauravThantry Yes, the id values can be used to replace el1, el2, el3. If you are using document ready you can add the startAnimate function call inside your document ready method.